# "Guess my Number" game in C++

Tags: c++, optimization, game

I have recently created my first game in C++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    cout<<"\tWelcome to Guess my Number!\n";
    const unsigned short kusiLower=1;
    const unsigned short kusiHigher=100;
    srand(time(0));
    unsigned short usiComp=rand()%kusiHigher+kusiLower;
    cout<<"Guess a number between 1 and 100: ";
    unsigned short usiUser;
    cin>>usiUser;
    unsigned short usiGuesses=1;
    while(usiUser!=usiComp)
    {
        cout<<((usiUser>usiComp)?"Your guess is too high.\n":"Your guess in too low\n");
        cout<<"Guess a number between 1 and 100: ";
        cin>>usiUser;
        ++usiGuesses;
    }
    cout<<"Congratulations! You guessed my number in "<<usiGuesses<<" guesses.";
}
```

And I came here to ask the standard question: can it be in any way optimized or improved?

Comment: Is it...... 42?

Comment: `using namespace std;` is still in your code.  Read this page for more information about its alternatives: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c

Answer (score 5):

a few remarks:

- Use int instead of unsigned short
- Don't use Hungarian naming ('kusi/usi' prefix) - nobody uses that.
- Add argc/argv parameters to main
- Dont import everything from std with `using namespace std`
- Add spaces around operators (=, != , ==, >>, << etc) and after 'while', 'if' etc.
- You have carefully used constants for the high/low boundaries, but your print statements  don't use these constants ("Guess a number between 1 and 100:")

Comment: "Use int instead of unsigned short" logically speaking an unsigned short is right in this case. The fact that `int`s and `short`s are usually both implemented with 4 bytes is a whole another story. In any case, why would he use a signed integer while the numbers he is dealing with are in the range [1..100]?

Comment: Why is short more logical - because its range is nearer to that of the 1..100 ? On that basis char would be the best fit. But using char could well be slower than int and I guess the same goes for short.  On unsigned, see http://soundsoftware.ac.uk/c-pitfall-unsigned

Comment: A good reason to use `short` is if the extra two bytes storage for an `int` is really going to be a problem (for example, if you're going to store billions of these values in files). The fact that the expected range of data _happen_ to fit the smaller type is not really relevant in the absence of some other reason to _want_ to fit the values into a smaller type.